# wifi speed too slow on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, iwlwifi

on my **android** device i get following speed.

```
download: 30 MBPS
upload: 7 MBPS
```

on **Ubuntu** i get following

```
download: 1.5 MBPS 
upload: 5 MBPS
```

I am not sure what is the issue, but it's pretty huge difference. 
Also, I never get option to choose which wifi to select, I always have to **nmcli** command for this, which is pretty much annoying.

it seems there is something wrong with network-manager. Also, the output of nmcli command is weird too.

```
nmcli d wifi
*  SSID  MODE  CHAN  RATE  SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A3**

```
 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5400]
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces**

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

**dmesg | grep iwl**

```
[   17.341311] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-19.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.341921] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-18.ucode failed with error -2
[   17.362098] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 17.352738.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[   17.401237] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[   17.401570] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   17.402016] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   17.495526] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[   17.592186] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0 wlp3s0: renamed from wlan0
[   18.853314] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.854805] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.915502] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   18.915951] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   25.445064] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   25.445615] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   25.514022] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[   25.514640] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  580.360687] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: invalid BA notification: Q 16, tid 0, flow 65535
[  580.361724] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: invalid BA notification: Q 16, tid 0, flow 65535
[  763.114810] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  763.115413] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  763.177355] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  763.177802] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  766.953653] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  766.954202] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  767.015290] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  767.015738] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  772.847845] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  772.848293] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  772.910331] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  772.910830] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  773.630022] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  773.630626] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  773.692161] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  773.692609] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  886.105647] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  886.106094] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  886.167232] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  886.167681] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  889.976743] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  889.977385] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  890.039415] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  890.039862] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  893.706400] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  893.706846] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  893.768962] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  893.769589] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  894.132001] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  894.132605] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  894.194665] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  894.195113] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1756.056376] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1756.057015] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1756.118667] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1756.119116] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1759.889556] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1759.890005] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1759.951394] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1759.951843] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1763.617368] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1763.617817] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1763.678790] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1763.679499] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1764.043503] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1764.044365] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1764.106480] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 1764.107243] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2196.017272] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2196.017877] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2196.080004] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2196.080453] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2199.882108] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2199.882557] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2199.944622] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2199.945069] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2203.594801] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2203.595638] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2203.656935] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2203.657542] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2204.041776] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2204.042225] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2204.104390] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2204.104839] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2580.990064] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2580.990512] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2581.052531] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2581.052989] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2584.854209] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2584.854652] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2584.916165] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2584.916780] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2588.584877] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2588.585335] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2588.647334] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2588.647940] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2588.998498] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2588.999104] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2589.060747] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2589.061352] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2941.030271] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2941.030719] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2941.092241] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2941.092690] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2944.867479] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2944.867929] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2944.929802] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2944.930261] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2948.579076] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2948.579525] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2948.641517] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2948.641987] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2948.996440] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2948.996888] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2949.058299] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 2949.058906] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3076.031848] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3076.032297] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3076.094235] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3076.094684] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3079.867559] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3079.868165] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3079.930376] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3079.930825] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3083.603125] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3083.603573] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3083.666154] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3083.666602] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3084.052282] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3084.052739] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3084.114197] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3084.114645] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3101.047231] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3101.047837] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3101.108938] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3101.109387] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3104.862022] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3104.862472] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3104.924189] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3104.924647] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3108.687628] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3108.688076] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3108.749077] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3108.749544] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3109.119927] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3109.120376] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3109.182518] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3109.182975] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3121.011873] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3121.012326] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3121.074483] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3121.074932] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3124.854541] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3124.854990] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3124.917004] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3124.917618] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3128.621977] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3128.622432] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3128.683763] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3128.684212] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3129.027499] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3129.028105] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3129.090106] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3129.090554] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3175.808542] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3175.809147] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3175.870477] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3175.871081] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3176.226349] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3176.226953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3176.288303] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3176.288750] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3573.996341] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3573.996789] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3574.057783] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3574.058232] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3577.847295] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3577.847931] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3577.909200] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3577.909650] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3581.568223] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3581.568985] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3581.630255] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3581.630860] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3581.961678] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3581.962284] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3582.023628] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3582.024077] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3723.976360] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3723.976809] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3724.038500] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3724.038949] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3727.836373] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3727.836821] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3727.898412] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3727.898860] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3731.563953] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3731.564559] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3731.626266] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3731.626716] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3731.986154] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3731.986604] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3732.047996] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[ 3732.048445] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` terminal commands.

Comment: If you remove everything except the firt 3 lines from `/etc/network/interfaces`, Network Manager will work normally. Regarding the speeds it is unclear how you measure.

Comment: @Pilot6 i updated the `/etc/network/interfaces` the file, however issue is same. I can't see any wireless connection or vpn connection from netwrok manager.

Comment: Did you restart NM after the change?

Comment: I restarted the network-manager and after that I restarted the whole machine. still the wifi network is greyed out and it says device not ready.

Comment: Please post the output of `dmesg | grep iwl` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 anyother information which would help understand the issue.

Comment: What is the kernel version?